# Does the Greater Invisibility spell also hide spell effects?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, invisibility

The spells [Greater Invisibility](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/greater-invisibility) turns a creature invisible:

> You or a creature you touch becomes invisible until the spell ends. Anything the target is wearing or carrying is invisible as long as it is on the target’s person.

Do magical effects affecting the target, such as
[Crown of Madness](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/crown-of-madness)'s crown, [Spirit Guardian](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/spirit-guardians)'s spirits, the [Heat Metal](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/heat-metal)'s red-hot glow, and the [Flame Blade](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/flame-blade)'s blade, also turn invisible?

Comment: Related: [Does casting while greater invisible make the spell effects also invisible?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/29734/does-casting-while-greater-invisible-make-the-spell-effects-also-invisible), but for D&D 3.5

Comment: Related: [What happens when I'm invisible and something I'm wearing had Light cast on it?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/56363/what-happens-when-im-invisible-and-something-im-wearing-had-light-cast-on-it)

Comment: Strangely this got erroneously flagged as duplicate even though it's not a duplicate of the linked question. Could we reopen please?

Comment: This seems like a duplicate to me. How is this question different?

Answer (score 0):

### The spell does not say so

Magical effects are not something the target is *wearing or carrying*. Normally the spell would [need to say](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/107637/what-is-the-source-of-the-spells-do-only-what-they-say-they-do-rules-interpret) that it also turns invisible ongoing effects to do so. It does not. Therefore, it should not turn such effects invisible.

If you were having a magical *light* spell going, the [light would still emanate](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/56363/what-happens-when-im-invisible-and-something-im-wearing-had-light-cast-on-it). One interesting corner case would be *disguise self* - this might mean that the illusion from disguise self would not turn invisible (although I as DM would likely rule otherwise).